# TLS expired Hyperledger Fabric orderers cannot be launched even with TLSHandshakeTimeShift option

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

TLS/MSP keys of My Hyperledger Fabric network were expired more than 500h ago. Becuase of the expirations, my orderers cannot be re-launched after it was stopped.

My orderer settings are:

- Hyperledger Fabric version 2.2
- RAFT Consensus

Following the documentation, I set `TLSHandshakeTimeShift` option as `650h` and set `NoExpirationChecks` as `true`. I checked these values had been set correctly via loggings.

```
2022-05-26 06:12:11.676 UTC [orderer.common.server] prettyPrintStruct -> INFO 003 Orderer config values:
    General.ListenAddress = "0.0.0.0"
    General.ListenPort = 7050
    General.TLS.Enabled = true
    General.TLS.PrivateKey = "/artifacts/tls/keystore/key.pem"
    General.TLS.Certificate = "/artifacts/tls/signcerts/cert.pem"
    General.TLS.RootCAs = [/artifacts/tls/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem]
    General.TLS.ClientAuthRequired = false
    General.TLS.ClientRootCAs = []
    General.Cluster.ListenAddress = ""
    General.Cluster.ListenPort = 0
    General.Cluster.ServerCertificate = ""
    General.Cluster.ServerPrivateKey = ""
    General.Cluster.ClientCertificate = "/artifacts/tls/signcerts/cert.pem"
    General.Cluster.ClientPrivateKey = "/artifacts/tls/keystore/key.pem"
    General.Cluster.RootCAs = [/artifacts/tls/tlscacerts/ca-cert.pem]
    General.Cluster.DialTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.RPCTimeout = 7s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBufferSize = 20971520
    General.Cluster.ReplicationPullTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationRetryTimeout = 5s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationBackgroundRefreshInterval = 5m0s
    General.Cluster.ReplicationMaxRetries = 12
    General.Cluster.SendBufferSize = 10
    General.Cluster.CertExpirationWarningThreshold = 168h0m0s
    General.Cluster.TLSHandshakeTimeShift = 650h0m0s // here
    General.Keepalive.ServerMinInterval = 1m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerInterval = 2h0m0s
    General.Keepalive.ServerTimeout = 20s
    General.ConnectionTimeout = 0s
    General.GenesisMethod = "file"
    General.GenesisFile = "/artifacts/genesis.block"
    General.BootstrapMethod = "file"
    General.BootstrapFile = "/artifacts/genesis.block"
    General.Profile.Enabled = false
    General.Profile.Address = "0.0.0.0:6060"
    General.LocalMSPDir = "/artifacts/msp"
    General.LocalMSPID = "BPLMSP"
    General.BCCSP.ProviderName = "SW"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.SecLevel = 256
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.HashFamily = "SHA2"
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.Ephemeral = true
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.FileKeystore.KeyStorePath = ""
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.DummyKeystore =
    General.BCCSP.SwOpts.InmemKeystore =
    General.Authentication.TimeWindow = 15m0s
    General.Authentication.NoExpirationChecks = true // here
...
```

Also, I replaced old, expired `MSP` with new `MSP`. Of course, both were issued by the same Fabric CA server.

So, the current situation is:

- TLS keys: Expired (I didn't replace them because they should be updated via Channel Config Update.)
- MSP keys: New

The problem is, when I restart each orderer, it looks fine at first, but it suddenly produces:

```
2022-05-26 06:12:29.535 UTC [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 0a4 TLS handshake failed with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=Orderer remoteaddress=10.0.4.45:55264
```

Then, it shut down with `Panic` error like below:

```
...
2022-05-26 06:12:36.533 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.replication] func1 -> WARN 0b9 Received error of type 'failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded' from {"CAs":[{"Expired":false,"Issuer":"self","Subject":"..."}],"Endpoint":"orderer2.bpl:7050"} channel=trust-chain-system-channel
2022-05-26 06:12:36.533 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.replication] func1 -> WARN 0ba Received error of type 'failed to create new connection: context deadline exceeded' from {"CAs":[{"Expired":false,"Issuer":"self","Subject":"..."}],"Endpoint":"orderer0.bpl:7050"} channel=trust-chain-system-channel
2022-05-26 06:12:36.533 UTC [orderer.common.cluster.replication] HeightsByEndpoints -> INFO 0bb Returning the heights of OSNs mapped by endpoints map[] channel=trust-chain-system-channel
2022-05-26 06:12:36.533 UTC [orderer.common.cluster] ReplicateChains -> PANI 0bc Failed pulling system channel: failed obtaining the latest block for channel trust-chain-system-channel
panic: Failed pulling system channel: failed obtaining the latest block for channel trust-chain-system-channel

goroutine 73 [running]:
go.uber.org/zap/zapcore.(*CheckedEntry).Write(0xc002b4e000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/zapcore/entry.go:230 +0x545
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).log(0xc000820df0, 0xc00252f804, 0x101c941, 0x21, 0xc002187c40, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:234 +0x100
go.uber.org/zap.(*SugaredLogger).Panicf(...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/go.uber.org/zap/sugar.go:159
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging.(*FabricLogger).Panicf(...)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/common/flogging/zap.go:74
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/cluster.(*Replicator).ReplicateChains(0xc002880840, 0xc0003bf000, 0xc002591a40, 0xc002880840)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/cluster/replication.go:166 +0x49d
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/onboarding.(*ReplicationInitiator).ReplicateChains(0xc000180200, 0xc0003bf000, 0xc002591840, 0x1, 0x1, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/onboarding/onboarding.go:183 +0x1e3
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/onboarding.(*InactiveChainReplicator).replicateDisabledChains(0xc000208a80)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/onboarding/onboarding.go:310 +0x225
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/onboarding.(*InactiveChainReplicator).Run(0xc000208a80)
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/onboarding/onboarding.go:288 +0x42
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server.initializeEtcdraftConsenter
    /go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/common/server/main.go:770 +0x218
```

From where should I investigate to solve this problem? Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: There are a few answers and some doc links to explore on this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65368127/hypereldger-fabric-admin-certs-and-tls-certs-expired

Comment: @JamesTaylor Thanks, but I already tried solutions suggested on the link and the network wasn't restored.
I will investigate more solution via some doc links. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like it's going to be tricky to recover but I understand that some people have had success with similar issues by asking on the mailing list http://lists.hyperledger.org/ - hope you find a solution.